# ngmodel:datefmt expected to be a date in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am having this issue in my app

Following is the snippet of my code Code snippet in comments

HTML

How i can make the input a ng-model of type date of vm.user as i am having this exception

Please help

Comment: <input type="date" name="dates" id="dates" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.dates">

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question to include that snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the solution for my problem

```
 `<input type="date" name="dates" id="dates" class="form-control" ng-model="dt" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" min="2016-01-01" max="2016-12-31" ng-change="m.user.date=dt.toISOString()">`
```

by changing the model value to ISO String helped me resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to bind the variables to your template scope without using the `$scope` service. Here is how you can do that:

HTML

```
    <input type="date" name="dates" id="dates" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.dates">

    {{vm.user.dates | date}}
```

JS

```
angular.module('angular-tests', [])
    .controller('TestCtrl', function () {
      var vm = this;

      vm.user = {};


    });
```

Comment: I get that exception when i get the value from local storage I want to save the date selected into vm.user.dates and also want to retrieve value without exception

Comment: I have got the solution for my problem Thanks for everybody who tried to resolve this issue  <input type="date" name="dates" id="dates" class="form-control" ng-model="dt"  placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" min="2016-01-01" max="2016-12-31" ng-change="m.user.date=dt.toISOString()">          by changing the model value to ISO String helped me resolve the issue